# How does Bloomberg calculate the 2 year swap rate using the current eurodollar futures prices?

Tags: bloomberg, eurodollars

I am getting hung up on the front and back stub periods and convexity adjustment. I've read a ton of similar posts but so far have not been able to tie out to this 2 Yr rate exactly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edited to include my quick math that does not have the convexity component, and the stub periods at the front and back end.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exactly how did you try calculating it yourself and what have you found out vs shown on BBG?

Comment: Might help to write down what page (ICVS, SWPM, ...) you look at and what product and settings you have. Did you manage to tie out a normal convexity adjustment?

Comment: @AKdemy Sure, this is the EDSF screen. For settings, I didn't touch anything aside from hitting "Adjust" to apply the convexity adjustment, which uses the inputs shown there

Comment: @Alper I edited the post to add what I've done without convexity adjustment and stub periods. In this case it's "pretty close", but I'd really like to get the 4.776 number shown in BBG

Comment: So essentially you haven't really computed anything yet? It is not pretty close, all your intermediate periods are way off. 6m should be 4.607 as opposed to 4.441. May I ask why you would like to replicate that number? In essence, it is several questions at once as it is now. FIrst, how convexity adjustment works. Secondly, how the 2y works and thirdly, how the stub is computed.You dont really show what you compute, apart from values (which means one would have to redo it manually).

Answer (score 3):

Convexity adjustment works like this
[image]

For references, see:

- [Hull. 2002. Options, Future and Other Derivatives](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01K94T4CG) p. 566.
- [Piterbarg and Renedo. 2006. Eurodollar Futures Convexity Adjustments in Stochastic Volalitiy Model. 2006](https://www.risk.net/journal-of-computational-finance/2160379/eurodollar-futures-convexity-adjustments-in-stochastic-volatility-models)

Note, cap normal vol is used (not caplet) and the mean reversion speed is not calibrated. Also, a slight approximation is made so that in the case of zero mean reversion (Ho-Lee model), the Hull White model reduces to Ho-Lee.

The 2yr value itself simply uses the Rate column, which is already convexity adjusted in your case. I am showing MMKt below, where you take ACT/360. The end is on 2022-10-17 which is 731 days, so you need 29 in the last period. It's the growth value over time for each period, turned into a yield measure,

[image]
where the green cell is computed as $(1099075.95/1000000-1)*360/731$.